# C# attribute to prevent method execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

I am trying to add a feature that lets data not be saved if an application setting is set to not save. I have many DataManagers that act as a data access layer in my application. My plan was to create 2 custom attributes `[DataRetention("PolicyNameHere")]` and `[InspectDataRetention]` that should be applied to methods on my data managers and, when present, the application should check if the RetentionSetting property on my `[DataRetention]` is set to DoNotSave, and if so, ignore. For example:

```
public class User
{

     public string Name {get; set;}

     [DataRetention("PII")]
     public long SSN {get; set;}
}

public class UserManager
{

     public User GetUser(int userId);

     [InspectDataRetention]
     public void UpdateUser(User user);

     public void Delete(User user);

}
```

In the above example, when UpdateUser is called on the UserManager, the application would first inspect the object and search for any [DataRetention] attributes. It would then grab the RetentionSetting property of the attribute (because the constructor for the attribute would set the retention setting) and if it is set to DoNotSave, then it would reset that field to its default value (in this case 0). However, if the User class were modified like below:

```
[DataRetention("PII")]
public class User 
{         
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public long SSN {get; set;}     
}
```

Then, when DoNotSave is configured, UpdateUser should simply return null (not perform the update method.

Is this possible with a custom attribute? If not, outside of an interceptor with a specific interface (i.e. RetainableDataManager : IDataManager and have all of my data managers implement the same IDataManager interface) is there any way to accomplish this behavior.

- MVC4 application
- Data Managers are POCOs
- Service layer in front of Data Layer (made of POCOs also)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at AOP (Aspect-Oriented Programming). Your `[InspectDataRetention]` attribute sounds a lot like an aspect that could be injected. [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) is a .Net implementation of AOP.

Comment: I wish I could add that to my project but I am a little constrained on the technologies I can use for now. Thanks for the idea though.